# This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, powershell, office-365, custom-list

I created Indexed columns for this list but i am still getting this error "This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator". I created views and When i am trying to display one of the created views in list view web part on a page. How can we display views in SharePoint if we have 20000 items in a list in SharePoint online. Is there any other way to achieve this requirement for SharePoint online ???

Answer (score 3):

We are not supported to increase the list view threshold in SharePoint Online.
As a workaround, I recommend you creating filtered views or use folders to manage the items.

Check the article to [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the option to use folders and/or filtered views you should have a hard look at the content in that list. If the list contains more than one content type you could split the list into one list per content type.